# Run Job every 4 days but first run should happen now

Tags: apscheduler

I am trying to setup [APScheduler](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler) to run every 4 days, but I need the job to start running now. I tried using `interval` trigger but I discovered it waits the specified period before running. Also I tried using cron the following way:

```
sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.add_executor('processpool')

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day='*/4')
def test():
    print('running')
```

One final idea I got was using a `start_date` in the past:

```
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=10, start_date=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=4))
```

but that still waits 10 seconds before running.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', days=4, next_run_time=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it skips it by a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the above answer, only difference being it uses add_job method.

```
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(dump_data, trigger='interval', days=21,next_run_time=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it skips it by a few milliseconds.

Comment: What do you mean by skipping it by a few milliseconds? APScheduler (3.x) has a precision of one second.